# Is "active" a keyword in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using a "customers" table having a column name as "active". The type of the column is tinyint(1) (boolean). The value for the column is 1 in the database for a particular customer. Following is what I am seeing on rails console for that customer record.

```
    2.1.0 :029 > customer.active
    => true 
    2.1.0 :030 > customer.active?
    => false
```

Shouldn't "customer.active?" return true instead of false? I checked by renaming column name as "enabled". In that case it returns true for both "customer.enabled" and "customer.enabled?". Is it happening because "active" word is being used for some other purpose in Rails or ActiveRecord code?.

Comment: I would set up a debugger, step into each of those `.active` calls, and see where it goes! C-;

Comment: The active? function is auto-generated, each column of the table will also have a corresponding function generated like this. I'm not sure what the function of these is though.

Comment: @vee actually, I think rails (4) does some magic to abstract tinyint(1) columns. in my project, a column of that type will give true or false (even when the value is manually set to 1 or 0). In my case the value returned is consistent with the query form '?', I don't know why OP is getting an inconsistency.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question directly I opened the rails console and typed the following code:

```
 :006 > class Entity < ActiveRecord::Base
 :007?>   end
 => nil 
 :008 > entity = Entity.new
 => #<Entity id: nil> 
 :009 > entity.active
NoMethodError: undefined method `active' for #<Entity id: nil>
 :010 > entity.active?
NoMethodError: undefined method `active?' for #<Entity id: nil>
```

**Note that you should create table `entities` to launch this code**

This shows that neither `active` nor `active?` are default model methods.

Methods with the column name and question are auto-generated, for example if you have boolean column `active` ActiveRecord will generate `active?` method.

If your methods return value another than column's one you can check if you redefined your method in the model. It can be redefined either in the model code directly or in the one of used gems that can add some methods by themselves.

For example, there is the [state_machine](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine) gem that adds `active?` method by itself

BTW, if you want to find your method definitions you can use the following code:

```
Customer.ancestors
```

to get ancestors chain. Than you can iteratively check each ancestor:

```
Customer.ancestors.select{|a| a.instance_methods.grep(/^active$/).any?}
```

to get ancestors with the required method.

Comment: The active? method will not be defined in any of the ancestors, it will be an instance method of the model itself (presumably defined using `define_method`)

Comment: You're right. But by default it should return the value of the boolean field. Added this to the answer.

Comment: Nikolay, I think you are right. I created a new project with default setup to test and the "active?" method worked as expected. As you have suggested I checked for "active?" method in the code of the gems I have included and I found it in the state_machine gem (which I am using). I think that is causing problem. I am going to rename my field to "enabled" to avoid the clash. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should edit your answer to specify that that particular gem will add the `active` method for future readers.

Comment: added this and an example from rails console